# Не могу установить LESS в IntelliJ Idea

Tags: less, jetbrains

[image: Dialogue screen screenshot after an attempt to install Less]

Помогите решить проблему в MacOS Sierra.

Пытаюсь установить LESS через следующее меню в IntelliJ Idea:

```
File / Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / Node.js and NPM
```

Делаю, как описывают [тут](https://youtu.be/eySc-pbksX8) [0:20 - 1:12], но не работает (см. прикрепленный файл).

Я не знаю, где необходимо использовать команду `sudo` (кажется глупым вставлять эту команду в поле Options, хоть я и пыталась)

У меня так же нет файла-карантина в папке IntelliJ Idea, как описывается [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251201/upgrading-intellij-idea-after-sierra-upgrade-does-not-have-write-access-to-pri/41383566#41383566).

Прошу помочь мне с решение проблемы, потому что я хочу, чтобы стили обновлялись каждый раз, когда я нажимаю кнопку 'Save' при работе со своими стилями.

Comment: С такой фамилией можно было и по-русски написАть... как-никак so. **RU** ...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В диалоге **Node.js and NPM** нет возможности запускать `npm` с `sudo`, но вы всегда можете сделать это в терминале: `sudo npm i -g less`
2. В целом, чтобы избежать необходимости использования elevated permissions при установке пакетов, рекомендуется устанавливать node.js через *node version manager* (**nvm**). См. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions